# Django Lib to create Facebook Canvas App

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-facebook, fandjango

I found at least three libraries which can be used to create Facebook Canvas Apps on Django:

1. PythonForFacebook - https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/django-facebook
2. Fandjango - https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango
3. Django For Facebook (fashiolista.com) - https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

Which one of these do you prefer for this task? Maybe there are some other more robust libs outhere? I'm a bit confused which one to choose.

Comment: another one: https://github.com/bigsassy/django-facetools